# Remove item from object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, oop

I'm really struggling removing an item from my object. The object has randomly generated keys so it makes it a little harder, but I can't remove the item from the object using `splice`... and I'm not sure why..

This is my object: `$scope.todos.trackers`

This is what `$scope.todos` looks like:

[image]

And this is what the `trackers` part of the object looks like:

[image]

So in order to try and delete one of the items in the `tracker` object (for instance the last item `note: "finally", value: 200), this is what my code looks like:

```
function removeIndividualTracker(uid, item) {
    angular.forEach($scope.todos.trackers, function(key, value) {
        angular.forEach(key, function(el, val) {
            console.log(key)
            console.log(item)
            if(key == item) {
                console.log($scope.todos)
                console.log($scope.todos.trackers)
                $scope.todos.trackers.splice($scope.todos.trackers.indexOf($scope.todos.trackers[value]), 1);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

but it doesn't work. I get an error of `$scope.todos.trackers.indexOf is not a function`.

Any ideas? I really don't know what to do.. Thanks!

Comment: $scope.todos.trackers is not an aray

Comment: if you are using html to call removeIndividualTracker function please upload html code also it can be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting that error because tracker is not an Array but rather an Object. Try something like this...

```
function removeIndividualTracker(key) {
     delete $scope.todos.trackers[key];             
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because tracker is an object.You could have used indexOf if tracker was an array of objects.You can read more about it from here : [MDN indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Now coming back to your question, you can delete by :

```
function removeIndividualTracker(key) {
   delete $scope.todos.trackers[key];             
}
```

You can read more about delete from here: [MDN delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)